# Node-Cron: how to ensure last job is complete

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I am using node-cron to send operational emails (currently searching for new emails that need to be sent every minute).

My function (operationalEmails) looks for mongodb records that have a sent flag = false, sends the email, then changes the sent flag = true.

If an iteration of the cron has a large payload of records to send, it *could* take more than a minute.

How do I ensure the last iteration of the cron is complete before starting a new one?

```
//Run every Min
cron.schedule("* * * * *", () => {
  operationalEmails();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to create a simple lock

```
const running = false;

function operationalEmails() {

   if (running) {
     return
   }

   running = true;
   // do stuff
   running = false;
}

//Run every Min
cron.schedule("* * * * *", () => {
  operationalEmails();
});
```

Comment: Ahh, easy enough! I made one update since operationEmails is a function I am importing:
var opEmailsRunning = false;
const runOpEmails = async () => {
  if (!opEmailsRunning) {
    opEmailsRunning = true;
    await operationalEmails();
    opEmailsRunning = false;
  } else {
    return;
  }
};

//Run every Min
cron.schedule("* * * * *", () => {
  runOpEmails();
});